# How to show default button back (arrow) in toolbar?

Tags: android

I want to set programmatically button back to my toolbar. How can I get a default drawable icon?

What I should write `bar.setNavigationIcon( HERE );`

If I set  `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"` to my toolbar, button is shown. But how to do it in code or even maybe how to get this attr in code?

P.S:
I don't want use `setSupportActionBar(..)`.

Tanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't and even don't want use setSupportActionBar

Answer (score 1):

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It is toolbar I can't and even don't want use setSupportActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetupToolbar:

```
private void SetupToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        setToolbar();
    }
```

In setToolbar() method you have to set the back icon in the tool bar

```
    private void setToolbar() {
        Toolbar ftoolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (ftoolbar != null) {

            ftoolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon_back);
            ftoolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Provide the Action 

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: R.drawable.icon_back raise ***cannot resolve symbol icon_back***

Comment: Add your back button drawable and name it as icon_back